# How do I get value data.length() to Ion (HTTP LIB:Library)?

Tags: android

this my code:

```
    String url = "http://x.x.x.x/docid.php" ;
    try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://domain.com/url.php")
                .asString()
                .withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                        result.getResult();
                        if(data.length()==0){
                            (why show error for data.length()?)

                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

at Ion Library I want to check data.length() from "url = "http://x.x.x.x/docid.php" ;" in Ion Library but error warnning "local variable data is accessed from within inner class".How do i fix it? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting data to `final`

e.g

```
    String url = "http://x.x.x.x/docid.php" ;
    try {
        final JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://domain.com/url.php")
                .asString()
                .withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                        result.getResult();
                        if(data.length()==0){
                            (why show error for data.length()?)

                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No worries. If it solved your issue, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decalre a `variable` as `Final` if you want to access it from inner class. Change your `data` to `Final`

```
 final JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
```

Comment: Thank you so much .I can fix it.